# Installing Geofirestore for Firebase 6.5.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, geofire, geofirestore

I'd like to use the Geofirestore library to do some location based queries. If I install it using CocoaPods, it will downgrade most of the firebase libraries to a compatible version. I'd like to keep up to date with Firebase but still be able to run Geofirestore/Geofire

This is the error I'm getting

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":


In Podfile:
    GeoFire (from `https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git`) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.5.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.5.0) was resolved to 6.5.0, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (= 6.1.0)



GeoFire (from `https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git`) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
  Firebase/Database (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.5.0, which depends on
    FirebaseDatabase (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)

Geofirestore (from `https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS.git`) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
  FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
```

Can someone help me out with this? I've read that people have been installing it manually..but I have no idea how to do that. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Arvid

Answer (score 1):

The GeoFirestore CocoaPod needs to be updated. See https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS/issues/19

Comment: Hi Paul! Thanks for the confirmation of that. 
I was just thinking, as Geofirestore.swift is just one file, wouldn't it be straightforward to download it, and just implement it manually?

Comment: You could do that or send a PR to update https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS/blob/master/Geofirestore.podspec#L46 and update the CocoaPod. Both assume that it works with Firebase 6 without other changes.